# Repetición de flujo mientras haya excepciones

Tags: java, excepciones

necesito ayuda para ejecutar esta excepcion, lo que pasa que solo se ejecuta una vez, y quiero que se repita hasta que se ingrese el dato correcto

```
do{
 try{
                    System.out.println("Desea jugar otra vez? \n si: 1 \n no: 0 ");
                    salida = Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
                }catch(NumberFormatException Exit){
                    System.out.println("no es un numero. se repetira el proceso");
                    salida = Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
                    salida = 1;
                }
            }while(salida != 1);

        }while(salida!=0);
```

Comment: Hola. Las excepciones, como su nombre sugiere, **deben ser excepcionales**. Es una pésima práctica andar lanzando excepciones dónde podrían usarse comparaciones elementales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Boolean isValid=true;
while( isValid ) try{
                System.out.println("Desea jugar otra vez? \n si: 1 \n no: 0 ");
                salida = Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
isValid=false;
            }catch(NumberFormatException Exit){
                System.out.println("no es un numero. se repetira el   proceso");

                valid = true;
}
```

Comment: Por lo menos deberías de añadir en la respuesta, porque tu código resuelve el problema. Eso aumenta la calidad de la respuesta. Te invito a leer: [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).